# How replace number with "-" randomly from a range of number using php

Tags: php, random

This is my sample data. i want to replace 2 number from this range randomly.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
```

i trying this code.

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <= $noof_q; $i++){
    for ($j=0; $j < $max_range; $j+=$increment){
        echo $min_range+$j.", ";
    }
    if ($j==$max_range) {
         echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And is something not working? How/where do you replace the random numbers?

Comment: i want just replace any 2 number from 1 to 10 with "--"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array in the range from 1 to 10, pick 2 random keys and replace them with the desired string:

```
<?php
$replaceString = '--';
for($x=1; $x<=5; $x++) {
    $range = range(1,10);
    $randomKeys = array_rand($range, 2);
    $range[$randomKeys[0]] = $replaceString;
    $range[$randomKeys[1]] = $replaceString;
    echo implode(',', $range);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope, this code help you

```
$firstRand = [rand(1, 10), rand(1, 10)];
$secondRand = [rand(1, 10), rand(1, 10)];

for ($i=1; $i < 11; $i++) {
    for ($j=1; $j < 11; $j++) {
        $myNumber = $j;

        if (
            $i === $firstRand[0] && $j === $firstRand[1] || 
            $i === $secondRand[0] && $j === $secondRand[1]
        ) {
            $myNumber = '-';
        }

        echo $myNumber . ", ";

        if ($j == 10) {
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```